# How to split delimited string with leading and trailing characters to array?

Tags: php, explode, trim, csv, substring

For example, if I have this string:

```
$stuff = "[1379082600-1379082720],[1379082480-1379082480],[1379514420-1379515800],";
```

I know can do this to split it into an array like this:

```
$stuff = str_replace(array("[","]"),array("",""),$stuff);
$stuff = explode(",",$stuff);
```

But it seems like there would be an easier way since the string is already in an array form almost. Is there an easier way?

Comment: what is this [1379082600-1379082720] - do you need content of [] to be treated as single value, as subtraction, or two sub elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get inside `[]` with `preg_match_all`. Try following:

```
preg_match_all("/\[(.*?)\]/",$stuff, $matches);
```

#### Output of $matches[1]

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '1379082600-1379082720' (length=21)
  1 => string '1379082480-1379082480' (length=21)
  2 => string '1379514420-1379515800' (length=21)
```

Answer (score 3):

> since the string is already in an array form almost.

It is not. A string and an array are quite different things in terms of programming language.

> Is there an easier way?

There is rather **no point** in looking for "an easier way". The way you have at the moment is pretty easy already.

Answer (score 1):

Trim the leading and trailing chars and then spit on `],[`:

```
$stuff = explode('],[', trim($stuff, '[],');
```

Comment: This solution improves the length, speed, and readability of the code. Whether or not it's "easier" is wholly subjective.

Answer (score 0):

This is as about as good as you're going to get I think

```
$stuff = array_filter(explode(",",str_replace(array("[","]"),"",$stuff)));

print_r($stuff);


    [0] => 1379082600-1379082720
    [1] => 1379082480-1379082480
    [2] => 1379514420-1379515800
```

Comment: Why did someone downvote this? It looks like a fine answer to me.

Comment: I am downvoting this method because it is incorrect / doesn't provide the desired output.  (It makes the same mistake as the OP's coding attempt)

Answer (score 0):

**Using a regex-based solution will be slower / less efficient than the other methods.**

If you are considering "simpler" to mean "fewer function calls, then I would recommend `preg_split()` or `preg_match_all()`.  I want to explain, though, that `preg_match_all()` adds a variable to the global scope and `preg_split()` doesn't have to.  Also, `preg_match_all()` produces a multidimensional array and you merely want a 1-dim array -- this is another advantage of `preg_split()`.

Here is a battery of options. Some are mine and some are posted by others.  Some work, some work better than others, and some don't work.  It's education time...

```
$stuff = "[1379082600-1379082720],[1379082480-1379082480],[1379514420-1379515800],";
// NOTICE THE TRAILING COMMA ON THE STRING!

// my preg_split() pattern #1 (72 steps):
var_export(preg_split('/[\],[]+/', $stuff, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));

// my preg_split() pattern #2 (72 steps):
var_export(preg_split('/[^\d-]+/', $stuff, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));

// my preg_match_all pattern #1 (16 steps):
var_export(preg_match_all('/[\d-]+/', $stuff, $matches) ? $matches[0] : 'failed');  

// my preg_match_all pattern #2 (16 steps):
var_export(preg_match_all('/[^\],[]+/', $stuff, $matches) ? $matches[0] : 'failed');

// Bora's preg_match_all pattern (144 steps):
var_export(preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/', $stuff, $matches) ? $matches[0] : 'failed');

// Alex Howansky's is the cleanest, efficient / correct method
var_export(explode('],[', trim($stuff, '[],')));

// Andy Gee's method (flawed / incorrect -- 4 elements in output)
var_export(explode(",", str_replace(["[","]"], "", $stuff)));

// OP's method (flawed / incorrect -- 4 elements in output)
$stuff = str_replace(["[", "]"], ["", ""], $stuff);
$stuff = explode(",", $stuff);
var_export($stuff);
```

If you want to see the [method demonstrations click here](https://3v4l.org/jAbpZ).

If you want to see the step counts [click this pattern demonstration](https://regex101.com/r/V9K1uT/1) and swap in the patterns that I have provided.